# c# mark average calc issue

Tags: c#, arrays, for-loop, average

```
        Console.Write ("How many students do you have?: ");
        student = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

        int[] numberOfStudents = new int[student];

        for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfStudents.Length; i++) {
            Console.Write ($"Enter student {i}'s current grade: ");
            numberOfStudents [i] = Convert.ToInt16 (Console.ReadLine ());
        }

        int sum = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents.Length; i++)
        {
            sum += numberOfStudents[i];
        }

        average = sum / numberOfStudents.Length;

        Console.WriteLine ($"Your student average is {average}.");
        Console.ReadLine ();
```

Basically the user inputs the number of students and that determines the length of the array.  The for loop gathers all the marks where the average is later calculated.

For some reason if the `numberOfStudents` length is 5 when the for loop gets to its fifth go around it ask for the student mark but when you enter it instead of getting the sum and calculating the average the program crashes with the `system.indexoutofrange` error.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Arrays are zero-based in C#. You've got that right for your *second* for loop (`for (int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents.Length; i++)`) but your *first* for loop acts as if they're one-based: `for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfStudents.Length; i++)`

Comment: Your first for loop is one-based. You should change that to zero-based.

Comment: You are using the same variable for two different purposes.  You have an array of number of students.  Each student should have an array of grades.  The length of the two arrays can be different.  Look at your code again.

Comment: Start first for from 0 and  i<numberOsStudents.Length

Comment: To shorten this code down you could just skip the array and create a `sum` variable and add to it in one for-loop, then count the sum out from that, although that might not fit the specification.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays start on index 0, so the first for-loop will run out of bounds when trying to select the last value (as the `i` variable will go from index `1 => 6`).

```
for (int i = 1; i <= numberOfStudents.Length; i++) { 
  // The i variable is starting on 1, loops til the index is greater than 5 (I.E., 6)
  Console.Write ($"Enter student {i}'s current grade: ");
  numberOfStudents [i] = Convert.ToInt16 (Console.ReadLine ());
  // On last fetch the variable i is 6, trying to fetch from array where last index is 5
  // will make the array throw an exception.
}
```

To fix this, you could either start the loop on index 0 and just loop it as you do in your second loop (`for (i=0;i<numberOfStudents.Length;i++)`) and then in your output add +1 to make the output start on 1 instead of 0.
Or by just changing the part where you fetch from the array to fetch `i - 1`.

Comment: Or just initialize the loop to start at 0

Comment: I thought of starting the loop at 0 but then the writeline would say "Student 0" which doesn't make sense.  @AndrewL but the above solution fixes both the problems.

Comment: That was the point. You would then print out i+1th student @AlexAgla .

Comment: You are missing a semicolon in that for loop!

Answer (score 6):

In C# array starting index is 0 not 1 so you just need to initialize  i in your first for loop with 0 and your code will work perfectly fine.
Try below code:

```
    Console.Write ("How many students do you have?: ");
    student = Convert.ToInt32 (Console.ReadLine ());

    int[] numberOfStudents = new int[student];

    for (int i = 0; i <= numberOfStudents.Length; i++) {
        Console.Write ($"Enter student {i+1}'s current grade: ");
        numberOfStudents [i] = Convert.ToInt16 (Console.ReadLine ());
    }

    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < numberOfStudents.Length; i++)
    {
        sum += numberOfStudents[i];
    }

    average = sum / numberOfStudents.Length;

    Console.WriteLine ($"Your student average is {average}.");
    Console.ReadLine ();
```